# Integration React Native and Express JS Restful API

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, express, react-native

I want to create a Restful API for my project created with Express JS and MongoDB. This is my code where retrieve all users by JSON encoding :

```
router.get('/GetAllUsers', function(req, res) {
  Users.find({}).then(eachOne => {
    res.json(eachOne);
  });
});
```

When I check it with `Postman`, It shows me correctly and with JSON format.
When I want to use `React Native` to fetch data, It shows me and error called :

`[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]`

When I check it with another JSON test address, It's correct but with this address, It has a problem, Also I checked my network and it doesn't seem have a problem.

This is my `React Native` code :

```
 import React from 'react';
    import {ScrollView, Text} from 'react-native';

    export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: []
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/Users/GetAllUsers", {method: "GET"}).
      then(response => response.json()).
      then(result => {
        this.setState({
          data: result
        });
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ScrollView>
          {
            this.state.data.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <Text key={index}>{item.username}</Text>
              ); 
            })
          }
        </ScrollView>
      );
    }

  }
```

Comment: You should definetly `catch` the `fetch` ...

Comment: @JonasW. If I used `async` you were correct but It not related to it, It was IP address problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this will help](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10404#issuecomment-267303151):

> The localhost is pointing to the environment in which the code is
>   running. The emulator emulates a real device while the simulator is
>   only imitating the device. Therefore the localhost on Android is
>   pointing to the emulated Android device. And not to the machine on
>   which your server is running. The solution is to replace localhost
>   with the IP address of your machine

So try to replace `localhost` with the IP address of your machine.